# Where do I find a courier?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I've got all 100% sync, the only thing missing is the thieves challenges, which I can't finish because I can't find a courier to catch. I know that there's no way to make them "appear", but are there any way to increase the chance for the, appearing, or is there a place or area where they appear more often?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, couriers don't have any special place where they spawn more, they are simply a rare spawn.

Ubisoft have addressed this in the [1.02 patch](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/739410-Assassin-s-Creed-III-Holiday-Patch-Spoilers) that was released for the XBOX and PS3 versions:

> Couriers will now appear more often in Boston and New York

Answer (score 0):

I found them to appear more in New York, but I've only seen 3 so far in all my game time.

Unsurprisingly they always appear when I'm busy with other things, so I have to break off and chase them down. They are a 'rare' spawn though, with some people saying they show up after you pay off a printer.

There is a spot listed here, with a confirmation post.
http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/assassins-creed-iii/178261-thief-challenge-take-down-courier-4.html#post3197409
However I've not tried this spot myself.

You might also try

> The place I remember them spawning more than once is in the market
>   that is in the middle of broadway.

Comment: They have been anything but rare for me in NY. They are constantly appearing whenever I am out collecting/killing.

Comment: Courier spawns are strange.  I got a lot of them, they seem to spawn when you're not on a mission and just running around collecting things.  I actually had one spawn _inside_ a fort while I was stealthing around trying to capture it.

Comment: I also saw one spawn inside a fort.

Comment: @ColinD - There was a patched that addressed them not spawning.  This answer was posted before that patch was released.